# INTEGER from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql takes no parameters in its __init__ method?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am attempting to create the models for my database and plan to use MySQL as the database. I want to create various attributes of the models unsigned MySQL `INTEGER`s and found articles which recommended importing the types from  `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql`, such as `INTEGER`, `BOOLEAN`, `VARCHAR` in order to specify MySQL specific constraints.

Here's my attempt:

```
import datetime

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER, BOOLEAN, VARCHAR

from app_name import app, db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER(usigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    realname = db.Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    email = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), nullable=False)
```

However, both variations of the line defining the `id` attribute, either:
`db.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER(usigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)`

or

`db.Column(INTEGER(usigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)`

fail with some variation of the following errors/traceback:

```
  File "/Users/Username/Development/App_Name/app_name/models/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    class User(db.Model):
  File "/Users/Username/Development/App_Name/app_name/models/__init__.py", line 10, in User
    id = db.Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER(usigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
  File "/Users/Username/Development/.virtualenvs/app_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/types.py", line 254, in __init__
    super(INTEGER, self).__init__(display_width=display_width, **kw)
  File "/Users/Username/Development/.virtualenvs/app_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/types.py", line 54, in __init__
    super(_IntegerType, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/Users/Username/Development/.virtualenvs/app_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/types.py", line 24, in __init__
    super(_NumericType, self).__init__(**kw)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Any insight into why my attempts have failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should be vigilant with the names of the attributes passed when you see an error like this.

What the error essentially says is `object.__init__` got an argument it wasn't expecting. This happens when you pass an argument to a `**kwargs` defined `__init__` that isn't processed and get sent up to `object.__init__` during a `super` call (for example).

Take the following snippet to reproduce a similar scenario:

```
class ExampleINTEGER:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # if unsigned is passed, grab it
        self.unsigned = kwargs.pop('unsigned', None)
        # yada yada for the rest of the expected args
        # if it isn't found, it gets forwarded :/
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

>>> ExampleINTEGER(unsigned=True)
<__main__.ExampleINTEGER at 0x7f41a048f978>
>>> ExampleINTEGER(usigned=True)
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4b996bd42b90> in <module>()
----> 1 ExampleINTEGER(usigned=True)

<ipython-input-13-6e67a8d8cdde> in __init__(self, **kwargs)
      4         self.unsigned = kwargs.pop('unsigned', None)
      5         # if it isn't found, it gets forwarded :/
----> 6         super().__init__(**kwargs)

TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

In your case, (as in the mock example I created) you misspelled `unsigned` with `usigned` :-)

Comment: That makes perfect sense when it's explained like that -- the `__init__` for `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.INTEGER` will only recognize specific keyword arguments passed and ignore any that don't match its criteria. Since I misspelled one of the parameter names, it was ignored and ended up incorrectly propagating to any further calls to different `__init__`s. Thank you for quick response, much appreciated!

Comment: exactly @SeanPianka. I'm not familiar with the inheritance tree of the specific class but somewhere across those `__init__`s that get called something got passed to `object` that shouldn't of had.